# Inner join from two not directly related models in Django

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, inner-join

Let's say I have model like this (all irrelevant fields removed for clarity):

```python
A(Model):
   someFields = ... #irrelevant in this case

B(Model):
   a = ForeignKey(A)
   my_data = ... #the data I need to retrieve

C(Model):
   user = ForeingKey(User)
   a = ForeignKey(A)
   class Meta:
      unique_together = ('user', 'a')
```

Now, how using Django queries can I get something equivalent to this SQL:

```sql
SELECT my_data FROM B WHERE B.a_id = C.a_id AND C.user = %user%
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lucky for you your query uses an existing relation.

```
B.objects.filter(a__c__user=someuser).distinct().values('my_data')
```

Comment: thanks, didn't know that `a__c` is going to be there automatically

Comment: actually I've just checked and it generates SQL like `SELECT my_data FROM B INNER JOIN A on B.a_id = A.id INNER JOIN C ON A.id = C.a_id WHERE user = someuser`, which makes unnecessary index scan on table A.

Comment: That's how Django works. If you want to do any better then you'll need to drop to raw queries.